# Extending EntityType add entity class to vars

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Beside an entity choice list in one of my forms, I need to add a link towards the admin page of this entity.

[image]

In order to generate the link, I need the class name of the entity

```
/admin/Customer
```

I'm extending [`EntityType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) to pass the class name, trying to set it in the vars.

```php
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['entity_class'] = $options['class'];
}

public function getParent()
{
    return EntityType::class;
}
```

Now if I try to use my new `entity_class` variable

```
{% block entity_widget -%}
    {{ form_widget(form) }} {{ entity_class }}
{%- endblock %}
```

I'm getting an error

> Variable "entity_class" does not exist...

If I try to dump the form vars

```
{% block entity_widget -%}
    {{ form_widget(form) }} {{ dump(form.vars) }}
{%- endblock %}
```

I'm seeing it

```php
//...
"placeholder_in_choices" => false
"entity_class" => "AppBundle\Entity\Customer"
//...
```

Trying to use `form.vars.entity_class` gives me another error saying the key is not set

**What am I doing wrong ? How can I access my custom variable ?**